# How to get specific child from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the above hierarchy- 
[image]

I want to get a reference to the objects that are underlined in red.

This is my code:

```
 mRootRefTravel = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/");
    mRootRefTravel.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v("START_TRAVEL", "data: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot firstSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    for (DataSnapshot secondSnapShot : firstSnapShot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.v("START_TRAVEL", "children: " + secondSnapShot.getValue());
                        Log.v("START_TRAVEL", "children: Trip: "+ secondSnapShot.child("Trip").getValue());

                        travel.setAccommodationCost((long) secondSnapShot.child("AccommodationCost").getValue());
                    }
                }

            }
            adapterStartTravel = new AdapterStartTravel(list, getActivity());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterStartTravel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This is my LOG:

```
08-27 08:11:34.661 5002-5002/com.amit.trawel V/START_TRAVEL: data: {Trip_0={Trip={TravelingExpenses=233, CarRent=78, PhoneCosts=130, NumOfTickets=3, NumOfCars=3, LodgingExpenses=986, TripId=1, Currency=shekel, AccommodationCost=16, FoodBudget=2100, NumOfRoom=244, NumOfPeople=3, AttractionsBudge=1100, OtherExpenses=555, FlightTicketTotalCost=500, ShoppingExpenses=200, NumOfDaysInsurance=569, LodgingBudget=1200, TotalTripSum=40000, ShoppingBudget=350, InsuranceCost=250, AttractionsExpenses=2, NumOfNightsAccommodation=2, TravelingBudget=470, NumOfDaysCarRent=1, OtherExpensesBudget=300, Destination=israel, FoodExpenses=5}}, Trip_1={Trip={TravelingExpenses=666, CarRent=60, PhoneCosts=100, NumOfTickets=4, NumOfCars=4, LodgingExpenses=78, TripId=2, Currency=dinar, AccommodationCost=40, FoodBudget=3000, NumOfRoom=44, NumOfPeople=2, AttractionsBudge=1500, OtherExpenses=555, FlightTicketTotalCost=400, ShoppingExpenses=300, NumOfDaysInsurance=77, LodgingBudget=1300, TotalTripSum=50000, ShoppingBudget=220, InsuranceCost=220, AttractionsExpenses=3, NumOfNightsAccommodation=3, TravelingBudget=500, NumOfDaysCarRent=2, OtherExpensesBudget=200, Destination=jordan, FoodExpenses=127}, Purchase_0={Lat=0.0, SumSpent=0, Lng=0.0, TripID=1, DBRowID=1}}}

08-27 08:11:34.662 5002-5002/com.amit.trawel V/START_TRAVEL: children: {TravelingExpenses=233, CarRent=78, PhoneCosts=130, NumOfTickets=3, NumOfCars=3, LodgingExpenses=986, TripId=1, Currency=shekel, AccommodationCost=16, FoodBudget=2100, NumOfRoom=244, NumOfPeople=3, AttractionsBudge=1100, OtherExpenses=555, FlightTicketTotalCost=500, ShoppingExpenses=200, NumOfDaysInsurance=569, LodgingBudget=1200, TotalTripSum=40000, ShoppingBudget=350, InsuranceCost=250, AttractionsExpenses=2, NumOfNightsAccommodation=2, TravelingBudget=470, NumOfDaysCarRent=1, OtherExpensesBudget=300, Destination=israel, FoodExpenses=5}

08-27 08:11:34.662 5002-5002/com.amit.trawel V/START_TRAVEL: children: Trip: null
```

And this is the EXCEPTION i`m getting-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
```

The exception is for this line-

```
travel.setAccommodationCost((long) secondSnapShot.child("AccommodationCost").getValue());
```

I want to be able to get to this child only after higher child was created. That`s why I cannot reference the final path as hard coded path, like that:

```
 mRootRefTravel = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/Trip_0/Trip");
```

Comment: Please provide more of the stacktrace. Which line is the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information

Comment: Your image shows no "AccommodationCost", so I'm not sure what you are trying to ask

Comment: The "AccommodationCost" value is located in the "Trip" child. If I can get to the "Trip" child(), I could retrieve this value

Comment: Is `secondSnapShot.getValue()` not the reference to that value already? For example, `secondSnapShot.child("Trip").getValue()` returned null because there is no "Trip" element in the second snapshot.

Comment: @cricket_007, you were right! I went one step further than I should have

Comment: Is this solved? If so, please close or answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @cricket_007 suggested, I got the reference to the desired child() with secondSnapShot.getValue()- one step further than I should to dig in that JSON tree.

I needed to write my getValue() like that:

```
travel.setAttractionsBudget((long) firstSnapShot.child("Trip").child("AccommodationCost").getValue());
```